# Filtro de Categoria Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou com dificuldade em implementar um filtro de categoria no meu site, que ao clicar em uma determinada categoria, somente ela fique visível.

Já consegui até criar um filtro de pesquisa, baseado no `input` digitado, porém agora quero fazer quando filtro que conforme usuário clique na categoria do Menu.

Segue abaixo `Javascript` que utilizei para implementar a pesquisa com `input`, estava pensando em usar o mesmo, porém receber o `input` quando usuário clicar no menu categoria.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var cat = $(this).attr('data-cad')
    if(cat == 'todos'){
        $('.cursos div').show()
    }else{
        $('.cursos div').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass(cat)){
                $(this).hide()
            }else{
                $(this).show()
            }
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Conteudos</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/geral.css">
  <!-- Javascript -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/filtros.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/filter-cat.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="corpo">

 <!--Area Total-->
 <div id="area">
 <!--Barra de Pesquisa-->
  <div id="barrapesquisa">
      <input type="text" id="txtEBusca" placeholder="Pesquisar..."/>
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- Fim da Barra de pesquisa-->
  <!-- Filtro -->
  <nav id="filtro">
   <ul>
    <p>Por Categorias</p>
    <li><div id="cordomenu1"></div> &nbsp <a href="#" clas="btn" data-cat="tec">Tecnologia</a> </li>
    <li><div id="cordomenu2"></div> &nbsp <a href="#" clas="btn" data-cat="gest">gestao</a> </li>
    <li> <div id="cordomenu3"></div> &nbsp <a href="#" clas="btn" data-cat="neg"  >Negocios</a> </li>
   </ul>
</nav><!--Fim Filtro -->
    <!-- Container -->
 <div id="container">
  <div id="curso">
            <div class="curso">      <!-- Curso-->
   <div class="tec">           <!--Categoria-->
             <div class="gallery-item">
        <div class="content-gallery">
         <h3>teste</h3>
         <h4>Tendências e desafios no mundo corporativo</h4>
         <div class="gestao"></div>
         <div class="videos"></div>
                    </div>
   </div>   <!--Fim do Classe categoria-->      
  </div> <!--Fim do Classe Curso-->
    </div><!--Fim do Curso-->

 <div id="curso">
            <div class="curso">      <!-- Curso-->
   <div class="neg">           <!--Categoria-->
             <div class="gallery-item">
        <div class="content-gallery">
         <h3>teste</h3>
         <h4>Tendências e desafios no mundo corporativo</h4>
         <div class="gestao"></div>
         <div class="videos"></div>
                    </div>
   </div>   <!--Fim do Classe categoria-->      
  </div> <!--Fim do Classe Curso-->
    </div><!--Fim do Curso-->

 <div id="curso">
            <div class="curso">      <!-- Curso-->
   <div class="gest">           <!--Categoria-->
             <div class="gallery-item">
        <div class="content-gallery">
         <h3>teste</h3>
         <h4>Tendências e desafios no mundo corporativo</h4>
         <div class="gestao"></div>
         <div class="videos"></div>
                    </div>
   </div>   <!--Fim do Classe categoria-->      
  </div> <!--Fim do Classe Curso-->
    </div><!--Fim do Curso-->
          
  </div><!--Fim Do container--> 
    </div><!--Fim Da Area-->
</div><!--Fim do Corpo -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara não consegui entender muito bem seu texto, exemplo: **agora quero fazer quando filtro conforme usuário clique na categoria do Menu**, poderia reescreve-lo para nós?

Answer (score 1):

Isso é bem mais simples e tem varias formas de fazer, uma forma simples eé assim...

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  var categoria = $(this).attr('data-categoria')
  
  $('.items li').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass(categoria)){
      $(this).hide()
    }else{
      $(this).show()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn" data-categoria="comida">Comida</button>
<button class="btn" data-categoria="bebida">Bebida</button>

<ul class="items">
  <li class="comida">Arroz</li>
  <li class="comida">Feijao</li>
  <li class="comida">Lasanha</li>
  <li class="bebida">Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT 1:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var cat = $(this).attr('data-cad')
    if(cat == 'todos'){
        $('.cursos div').show()
    }else{
        $('.cursos div').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass(cat)){
                $(this).hide()
            }else{
                $(this).show()
            }
        })
    }
})
```

```css
a{
padding: 20px;
color: blue;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
color: red;
}


.cursos{
margin-top: 50px;
}

.cursos .curso{
padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-cad="todos">Todos</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-cad="front">Front-End</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-cad="back">Back-End</a>
    
    <div class="cursos">
        <div class="curso front">Javascript</div>    
        <div class="curso front">HTML</div>
        <div class="curso front">CSS</div>
        <div class="curso back">NodeJS</div>
        <div class="curso back">MongoDB</div>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2:

Dessa vez fiz baseado no seu codigo, segue o exemplo, basta testar.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    
    var cat = $(this).attr('data-cat')
    alert(cat)
    if(cat == 'todos'){
        $('.cursos div').show()
    }else{
        $('#container .curso .tag').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass(cat)){
                $(this).hide()
            }else{
                $(this).show()
            }
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Conteudos</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/geral.css">
       
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="corpo">
      <!--Area Total-->
      <div id="area">
      <!--Barra de Pesquisa-->
      <div id="barrapesquisa">
         <input type="text" id="txtEBusca" placeholder="Pesquisar..."/>
         <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- Fim da Barra de pesquisa-->
      <!-- Filtro -->
      <nav id="filtro">
         <ul>
            <p>Por Categorias</p>
            <li>
               <div id="cordomenu1"></div>
               &nbsp <a href="#" class="btn" data-cat="tec">Tecnologia</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
               <div id="cordomenu2"></div>
               &nbsp <a href="#" class="btn" data-cat="gest">gestao</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
               <div id="cordomenu3"></div>
               &nbsp <a href="#" class="btn" data-cat="neg"  >Negocios</a> 
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <!--Fim Filtro -->
      <!-- Container -->
      <div id="container">
      <div id="curso">
         <div class="curso">
            <!-- Curso-->
            <div class="tag tec">
               <!--Categoria-->
               <div class="gallery-item">
                  <div class="content-gallery">
                     <h3>teste</h3>
                     <h4>Tendências e desafios no mundo corporativo</h4>
                     <div class="gestao"></div>
                     <div class="videos"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!--Fim do Classe categoria-->      
            </div>
            <!--Fim do Classe Curso-->
         </div>
         <!--Fim do Curso-->
         <div id="curso">
            <div class="curso">
               <!-- Curso-->
               <div class="tag neg">
                  <!--Categoria-->
                  <div class="gallery-item">
                     <div class="content-gallery">
                        <h3>teste</h3>
                        <h4>Tendências e desafios no mundo corporativo</h4>
                        <div class="gestao"></div>
                        <div class="videos"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--Fim do Classe categoria-->      
               </div>
               <!--Fim do Classe Curso-->
            </div>
            <!--Fim do Curso-->
            <div id="curso">
               <div class="curso">
                  <!-- Curso-->
                  <div class="tag gest">
                     <!--Categoria-->
                     <div class="gallery-item">
                        <div class="content-gallery">
                           <h3>teste</h3>
                           <h4>Tendências e desafios no mundo corporativo</h4>
                           <div class="gestao"></div>
                           <div class="videos"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!--Fim do Classe categoria-->      
                  </div>
                  <!--Fim do Classe Curso-->
               </div>
               <!--Fim do Curso-->
            </div>
            <!--Fim Do container--> 
         </div>
         <!--Fim Da Area-->
      </div>
      <!--Fim do Corpo -->
          
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
     

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como sou nnoob ainda em HTML e JavaScript,tentei implementa conforme sugestão sem Êxito.Por caso teria um forma de implementar declarando dentro de uma DIV e utilizando o href.

Comment: Sim, vou dar um exemplo...

Comment: @RafaelLuz Editei a resposta, deixei as duas formas.

Comment: editei meu 1º código conforme sugestão sua,porém não obtive êxito,então peguei exemplos que você,debugei no ambiente,não funcionou também.

Comment: @RafaelLuz Vou fazer baseado no seu proprio codigo

Comment: @RafaelLuz Editei a minha resposta, com a correção do seu codigo.

Comment: obrigado pela moral,contudo tentei implementar conforme sugestão,sem  êxito.Irei estudar mais sobre o tema e outras forma de implementar esse filtro.Como tratasse de código legado que estou dando manutenção,irei ver nesse tanto de elementos(DIV's) que acho aonde esta X da questão.