# Ordenar array de Objetos JS

Tags: javascript

Fala Galera, comecei a estudar JS e criei uma função list que cria a lista que verifica o sexo do usuário e cria uma lista conforme abaixo.

```
<ul>
     <li>Diego é homem e possui 23 anos</li>
     <li>Gabriela é mulher e possui 18 anos</li>
     <li>José é homem e possui 30 anos</li>
     <li>Maria é mulher e possui 27 anos</li>
</ul>

<button onClick="">Ordenar por nome</button>
<button onClick="">Ordenar por idade</button>

<button onClick="">Exibir apenas homens</button>
<button onClick="">Exibir apenas mulheres</button>
<button onClick="">Exibir todos</button>
```

Os dois primeiros botões devem ordenar a lista, por nome e por idade. Os outros 3 botões devem aplicar filtros na lista exibindo apenas homens, apenas mulheres ou todos. O filtro deve funcionar junto da ordenação então deve ser possível filtrar apenas homens e ordenar por idade.

Já criei a função para ordenar por idade, dei um console log e está ordenando minha dúvida é como faço para que só ordene quando clicar no botão

```js
var users = [{
    nome: 'Diego',
    idade: 23,
    sexo: 'M',
  },
  {
    nome: 'Gabriela',
    idade: 18,
    sexo: 'F',
  },
  {
    nome: 'José',
    idade: 30,
    sexo: 'M',
  },
  {
    nome: 'Maria',
    idade: 27,
    sexo: 'F'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Amanda',
    idade: 26,
    sexo: 'F'
  }
];

function list() {
  // Cria a lista do elemento
  var listElement = document.createElement("ul");

  for (let value of users) {
    sexo = value.sexo;

    switch (sexo) {
      case "F":
        value.sexo = "Feminino";
        users = value.nome + " é " + value.sexo + " e possui " + value.idade + " anos."
        break;

      case "M":
        value.sexo = "Masculino";
        users = value.nome + " é " + value.sexo + " e possui " + value.idade + " anos."
        break;
    }

    //Cria a lista de item
    var itemElement = document.createElement('li');

    //Define seu conteudo
    itemElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(users));

    //Adiciona um item a lista
    listElement.appendChild(itemElement);
  }

  return listElement;
}

function byAge(a, b) {
  return a.idade - b.idade;
}

//console.log(users.sort(byAge));

// Add the contents of options[0] to #foo:
document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(list(users));
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="app"></div>

  <button class="btn btn-info" onClick="byName()">Ordenar por nome</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" onClick="byAge()">Ordenar por idade</button>

  <button class="btn btn-info" onClick="">Exibir apenas homens</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" onClick="">Exibir apenas mulheres</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" onClick="">Exibir todos</button>
</div>
```

Comment: A sua questão é de como chamar o `console.log(users.sort(byAge))` quando clica num botão ?

Comment: Não, pelo console.log eu já vi que a função de ordenar está funcionando, eu preciso entender como faço para que a lista ordene quando eu clicar no botão de ordenar

Comment: Qual a diferença entre isso e o que eu disse ? A mim parece-me igual, excetuando o pormenor de ser um botão especifico, o de ordenar

Comment: resumidamente clica no botão ordenar por idade, ele não funciona não ordena, quero saber como faço para que ele ordene a lista que eu criei pela função list()

Comment: Eu parece me que a sua questão deve ser outra, ou então baralhou-se no código. Ainda assim, se quer ordenar por idade quando clica no botão `Ordenar por idade` então não basta trocar o `onclick` e respetiva função como já fez ? Algo como : `<button class="btn btn-info" onClick="ordenarIdade()">Ordenar por idade</button>`, e depois no JS `function ordernarIdade(){ users.sort(byAge); list(); }`. É isso que pretende fazer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Já criei a função para ordenar por idade, dei um console log e está ordenando minha dúvida é como faço para que só ordene quando clicar no botão

Parece que a sua dificuldade é chamar a função pelo botão, mas, também um pouco de lógica, resolvi com isso criar uma estrutura básica onde uma função mostra os dados, outra função formata a exibição e a outras mostras os dados filtrados e ordenados.

***Exemplo:***

```js
var users = [{
    nome: 'Diego',
    idade: 23,
    sexo: 'M',
  },
  {
    nome: 'Gabriela',
    idade: 18,
    sexo: 'F',
  },
  {
    nome: 'José',
    idade: 30,
    sexo: 'M',
  },
  {
    nome: 'Maria',
    idade: 27,
    sexo: 'F'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Amanda',
    idade: 26,
    sexo: 'F'
  }
];

var show = 'all';

function textList(u) {
  return u.nome + " é " + (u.sexo == 'M' ? "Masculino" : "Feminino") + " e possui " + u.idade + " ano(s)";
}

function byName() {
  users.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.nome < b.nome ? -1 : (a.nome > b.nome) ? 1 : 0;
  });
  list();
}

function byAge() {
  users.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.idade < b.idade ? -1 : (a.idade > b.idade) ? 1 : 0;
  });
  list();
}

function showUsers(value) {
  show = value;
  list();
}

function list() {
  var listElement = document.getElementById("data");
  listElement.innerHTML = '';
  for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (show == 'all' || users[i].sexo == show) {
      var itemElement = document.createElement('li');
      itemElement.innerHTML = textList(users[i]);
      listElement.appendChild(itemElement);
    }
  }
}
list(); // init
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="data">
</ul>
<button class="btn btn-info" onClick="byName()">Ordenar por nome</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" onClick="byAge()">Ordenar por idade</button>

<button class="btn btn-info" onClick="showUsers('M');">Exibir apenas homens</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" onClick="showUsers('F');">Exibir apenas mulheres</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" onClick="showUsers('all');">Exibir todos</button>
```

Foi divido em funções para que ao clicar no botão possam executar o filtro ou ordenação e logo após atualizar a lista exibir com a modificação. Nos botões no evento `onClick` foi chamada essas funções com os devidos parâmetros.

***Itens importantes:***

- [Como ordenar uma array de objetos com array.sort()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46600/como-ordenar-uma-array-de-objetos-com-array-sort)
- [Filtro de Categoria Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240659/filtro-de-categoria-javascript)
- [Criando um filtro de busca customizável com JavaScript funcional](https://medium.com/@gabrielchiconi/criando-um-filtro-de-busca-customiz%C3%A1vel-com-javascript-funcional-410956e9e608)

Comment: Virgilio era exatamente isso, valeu pela ajuda e links